# model selection with tweedie distributions in MuMIn package R

Tags: r, distribution, glm, mumin, tweedie

I'm trying to do AICc model selection and model averaging with tweedie (compound Poisson) distributed data in R.

I was working with the AICcmodavg R package with no success, then decided to try out the MuMIn package when I came across the suggestion here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141806/glm-model-selection-using-aicc-with-tweedie-distribution) that

> "You can use AICtweedie directly in MuMIn's functions, just specify it as a rank argument."

I set up my models as follows My response variable (NVIR) is catch-per-unit-effort of eastern newt adults and my explanatory variables are various habitat characteristics of my sampling sites.

```
m1<- glm(NVIR~Water_T+cond+DO+ORP+pH+max_depth+type, 
    family = tweedie(link.power=0, var.power=1.3), data = cpue)
m2<- glm(NVIR~Water_T+cond+DO+ORP+pH+littoral_slope+type, 
    family = tweedie(link.power=0, var.power=1.3), data = cpue)
m3<- glm(NVIR~pH+DO+cond+max_depth+type, 
    family = tweedie(link.power=0, var.power=1.3), data = cpue)
m4<- glm(NVIR~pH+DO+cond+littoral_slope+type, 
    family = tweedie(link.power=0, var.power=1.3), data = cpue)
m5<- glm(NVIR~cond+type+pH+max_depth, 
    family = tweedie(link.power=0, var.power=1.3), data = cpue)
```

and then tried this line

```
model.sel(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, rank = AICc, rank.args = AICtweedie)
```

and received the error

```
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "function"
In addition: Warning message:
In model.sel.default(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, rank = AICc, rank.args =   AICtweedie) :
models are not all fitted to the same data
```

Alternatively, I also tried this line

```
model.sel(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5, rank.args=AICtweedie)
```

and got this error:

```
Error in get(x) : object 'Tweedie' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In model.sel.default(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, rank.args = AICtweedie) :
models are not all fitted to the same data
```

I'm wondering whether the problem is with my code, or if the tweedie family is incompatible with this package.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried using `AICtweedie` for the `rank` argument instead of the `rank.args` argument?

Comment: @aosmith This would be my suggestion too. Try just using `model.sel(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5, rank=AICtweedie)`

Comment: thanks! I tried that as well 'model.sel(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5, rank=AICtweedie)' and got the error 'Error in get(x) : object 'Tweedie' not found'

Comment: It is fixed now in MuMIn 1.40.8 (currently only on R-Forge).

Comment: Thanks all! I appreciate your time and comments.

Answer (score 0):

rank = tweedie::AICtweedie

Just for anyone who comes across this

Comment: do you have any idea why `rank=AICtweedie` didn't work for the OP (as reported in comments)? Is there an `AICtweedie` object in more than one package?

Comment: @BenBolker `model.sel` assumes `family(model)$family` would be a name of the family function. In this case it is `"Tweedie"` not `"tweedie"` and hence the problem. There are also other problems with handling `tweedie` family - I'll look into it soon.

Comment: hmm.  In `glmmTMB`, `beta_family()` gives rise to an object with `$family` equal  to "beta".  Is there going to be a way to deal with this more generally ... ? (We might be able to change the `$family` component without breaking anything ... let me know offline if that would be the best way ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Don't worry about it - I see that the code should not expect all `family` objects to conform to the standard structure, so I guess I just remove that bit (which is not crucial in any way). Even the `MASS::negative.binomial` is a pain with it with its `$family` such as `"Negative Binomial(1.23)"`.

Comment: Thanks all! I appreciate your time and comments.